# How to get a new instance of the type that implemented a particular interface

Tags: go

I declare an interface like this:

```
type TimeIndexedTable interface {
    Get(string) ([]float64, error)
    Set(string, []float64) error
    GetIndex() []time.Time
    SetIndex([]time.Time)
    ListColumns() []string
}
```

And then I want to implement a function called Resample

```
Resample(**UNDERLYING** TimeIndexedTable, interval time.Duration, functionMap map[string]string)(TimeIndexedTable ,error){
//give me a new instance of the UNDERLYING
}
```

So, I would like to know how to get the **UNDERLYING** type and initialize an empty instance of it.

I apologize if this question is confusing or has been asked before, but I have looked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [reflect.New](https://godoc.org/reflect#New) to create a new value of the type.

```
func Resample(src TimeIndexedTable, interval time.Duration, functionMap map[string]string)(TimeIndexedTable ,error){

    t := reflect.TypeOf(src)
    var v reflect.Value

    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        // The interface is on the pointer receiver. 
        // Create a pointer to a new value.
        v = reflect.New(t.Elem())
    } else {
        // The interface is on the value receiver. 
        // Create a new value.
        v = reflect.New(t).Elem()
    }

    // Get the value as a TimeIndexedTable using a type assertion.
    dst := v.Interface().(TimeIndexedTable)

    ...
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Xv0LIktGsTm)

Comment: thanks, works great! just curious, is doing this frowned up? like is it an acceptable design pattern to use reflect package a lot?

Comment: @devshoe You can avoid using the reflect package by passing the destination as an argument. Given how tricky the code is here, I'd consider that approach.